# Json response not writing provided users into csv file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, csv

`My python version -3.6.9`. With the below python code I'm trying to write the `json` response into `csv` file.

```py
import requests
import json
import csv

user_list = '''robby.cornelissen 
adrian.charles
tyler.swenson 
brandon.miller
nathan.gallete'''

ports = [2316, 2340, 2380, 2482]

users = user_list.split('\n')
fname = "result.csv"
with open(fname, "w") as file:
    csv_file = csv.writer(file,lineterminator='\n')
    csv_file.writerow(["depotFile", "host", "isgroup", "line", "perm", "unmap", "user"])
    for user, port in zip(users, ports):
        print(f'from csv and other method here is the user and port: {user}, {port}')
        url = f'http://198.98.99.12:46567/{port}/protects/{user}'
        print(f'grab data from rest api: {url}')
        response = requests.get(url, auth=('tool-admin', 'password'))
        
        data = requests.get(url).json()
        for item in list(data):
            csv_file.writerow(item.values())
```

**Current Output:-**

```
depotFile          host  isgroup  line   perm    unmap   user
//LIB/Include/...   *              12    read           2G_Members
//Prj/LIB/...       *              15    write          4G_Members  
//AND/KIO/...       *              16    read           5G_Members
//PRJ/MM/SRC/...    *              17    write          4G_Members
//Hon/Sam/...       *              18    read           6G_Members
```

**Current problem as follows,**

1. In the `user_list` section passing multiple user ids and in `ports` section passing multiple port numbers, however currently it is writing response of single user-id only. But it need to write response for all provided users list one by one.
2. Also in the `output csv` file would need additional two columns with `user_list` and `ports`.   I.e.(`{port} & {user}` need to append in csv file).

**Expected output:-**

```
depotFile          host  isgroup  line   perm    unmap   user       user_list           port
//LIB/Include/...   *              12    read           2G_Members  robby.cornelissen   2316
//Prj/LIB/...       *              15    write          4G_Members  adrian.charles      2316
//AND/KIO/...       *              16    read           5G_Members  tyler.swenson       2340
//PRJ/MM/SRC/...    *              17    write          4G_Members  brandon.miller      2380
//Hon/Sam/...       *              18    read           6G_Members  nathan.gallete      2482
```

Need help to fix this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `user` and `port` to each `data` row.

```
        for item in data:
            item = list(item.values()) + [user, port]
            csv_file.writerow(item)
```